# Автоматический запуск сервера Postgres при входе в систему

Tags: postgresql, macos

Как сделать автоматический запуск сервера postgres при входе в систему os x?

Answer (score 1):

Для автозапуска выполните:

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

Comment: именно так нужно.